# Search a range with optional parameters

Tags: sql-server, case

I am retrieving data from a SQL Server with multiple parameters. In this example, FirstName, LastName, and Age. I need to search within a range of ages. For example, I need to search by FirstName and where the FromAge is >= 5 and the ToAge is <= 20. I can't seem to figure out how to search a range using the case statement.

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (FirstName = CASE WHEN @FirstName = '' THEN FirstName ELSE @FirstName 
END)
AND (LastName = CASE WHEN @LastName = '' THEN LastName ELSE @LastName END)
AND (AGE = CASE WHEN @AgeFrom = '' AND @AgeTo = '' THEN AGE ELSE AGE >= 
@AgeFrom AND AGE <= @AgeTo END)
```

I should be able to search the age fields by a range, or, if no data is provided for age, do not search by age.

Comment: Perhaps you want two separate case statements. For example `age >= case when @agefrom = '' then AGE else @agefrom end and age <= case when @ageto = '' then age else @ageto end`

Comment: Case is an expression, not a statement. To that end it is used to return a scalar value, not define logic. Secondly you should not be storing age in the first place. As soon as your save the data it is stale. Age should be calculated. Instead you should record a birthdate or other relevant date indicating the "beginning". Then this becomes a LOT simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to specify a minimum age without specifying a maximum, and visa-versa:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    (nullif(@FirstName, '') is null or FirstName = @FirstName)
AND (nullif(@LastName, '') is null or LastName = @LastName)
AND (nullif(@AgeFrom, '') is null or AGE >= @AgeFrom)
AND (nullif(@AgeTo, '') is null or AGE <= @AgeTo)
```

Or, a more compact version:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE FirstName = isnull(nullif(@FirstName, ''), FirstName) -- might not perform as well as first example
AND LastName = isnull(nullif(@LastName, ''), LastName)      
AND AGE between isnull(nullif(@AgeFrom, ''), AGE)           -- performance hit will be less or even negligible if Age is a numeric type
            AND isnull(nullif(@AgeTo, ''), AGE)
```

Your age column as well as the 2 age parameters should really be numerical types.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (LEN(@FirstName) = 0 OR FirstName = @FirstName)
       AND
      (
        (@AgeFrom IS NULL AND @AgeTo IS NULL)
        OR
        (Age BETWEEN @AgeFrom AND @AgeTo)
      )
```

It's a bad idea to use string for date, instead use `DATE` datatype and check for `NULL`s. a `DATE` can be `NULL` or has a date, so if you assign `''` to a date, the results is not `''`, it's `01/01/1900`.